# Abstract methods in a Java interface

Tags: java, inheritance

Something I've seen a lot but never thought to question it... In a Java **Interface**, what is the difference between:

```
public void myMethod();
```

and

```
public abstract void myMethod();
```

I understand the purpose of the abstract keyword in a Java class, but what purpose does it serve (if any) in an interface?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both declarations are completely the same, all interface methods do not have implementation (are abstract) hence the `abstract` keyword is redundant. In my opinion writing `abstract` in this case increases verbosity of code.

Comment: And the modifier public is also redundant.

Answer (score 8):

All method declarations are both `public` and `abstract` in an interface. No point specifying it at all.

Only `void myMethod();` is really needed here.

Answer (score 6):

From [Java Specification:](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/interfaces.doc.html#32392)

> - 9.4 Abstract Method Declarations
>     ..
>     ..
>     ..
>
> Every method declaration in the body
>   of an interface is implicitly
>   abstract, so its body is always
>   represented by a semicolon, not a
>   block.
>
> Every method declaration in the body
>   of an interface is implicitly public.

Answer (score 2):

Both `public` and `abstract` are redundant here. I personally prefer omitting them both because in my opinion they're both just noisy in this case.

Whilst you could of course include them, I think it's perfectly reasonable to assume that anyone reading your code knows that all methods in an interface must be public and abstract - it's a well understood feature.

Answer (score 1):

As already said interface methods ARE `public` and `abstract`. It is now [discouraged](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/interfaces.doc.html#78651) to specify them as public abstract:

> For compatibility with older versions of the Java platform, it is permitted but discouraged, as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the abstract modifier for methods declared in interfaces.
>
> It is permitted, but strongly discouraged as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the public modifier for interface methods.

And for completeness [interface fields](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/interfaces.doc.html#78642) ARE `public` `static` and `final`...

Comment: Thanks for the useful link, it's odd that adding "public abstract" is the default behaviour in the latest Eclipse refactoring tools.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can declare explicitly , All methods in an interface are implicitly public and abstract. The compiler will complain only if you try to make them non abstract ( by providing the body ) and private.